# How to convert hour number from 24h to 12h format without any conditional operation?

Tags: c

The following code converts hour from 24hr format to 12hr format. The input is an integer `Hrs_24_Format`, which has possible values from 0 to 23.

```
if ( Hrs_24_Format > 12 )
    Hrs_12_Format = Hrs_24_Format – 12;
else if (Hrs_24_Format == 0)
    Hrs_12_Format = 12;
else
    Hrs_12_Format = Hrs_24_Format;
```

How to develop this logic without any condition (no branching on its flowchart)?

Comment: That goal is rather dubious. Now the code is well readable, if you rewrite it using `max()` and `min()` it will become cryptic.

Comment: Please provide some [mre] in your question. If on Linux, read [time(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) and use [time(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html), [localtime(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3.html) and [strftime(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html). How do you deal with [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second)?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `Hrs_24_Format` is an integer, this should do what you want:

```
(Hrs_24_Format + 11) % 12 + 1
```

This produces the following values:

```
 0  12
 1   1
 2   2
 3   3
 4   4
 5   5
 6   6
 7   7
 8   8
 9   9
10  10
11  11
12  12
13   1
14   2
15   3
16   4
17   5
18   6
19   7
20   8
21   9
22  10
23  11
24  12
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a modulo calculation:

```
Hrs_12_Format = ((Hrs_24_Format + (12-1) % 12) + 1;
```

You need to temporarily subtract 1 from the input for the modulo operation in order to get values from 1 to 12 instead of from 0 to 11.

Then you also need to add a constant positive offset before subtracting 1, to avoid an underflow when the input is 0. Using any multiple of 12 mathematically has no effect on the result, so practically you just use 12.

Visualization:

```
        0  1  2 ... 11 12 13 ... 22 23
+12-1: 11 12 13 ... 22 23 24 ... 33 34
 % 12: 11  0  1 ... 10 11  0 ...  9 10
   +1: 12  1  2 ... 11 12  1 ... 10 11
```

Note that the implementation of the modulo operator still has to use the condition "if x > 12" in some way under the covers. The branching is an inherent part of this calculation.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wish to use any conditional operators, and don't have any branches, a possible solution is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int Hrs_12_Format, Hrs_24_Format;

    Hrs_24_Format = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    Hrs_12_Format =  (Hrs_24_Format +11)%12 +1)

    printf("The 12 hour format is %d\n",Hrs_12_Format);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
./a.out 0   
The 12 hour format is 12
./a.out 1   
The 12 hour format is 1
./a.out 2   
The 12 hour format is 2
./a.out 3   
The 12 hour format is 3
.
.
.
./a.out 24
The 12 hour format is 12
./a.out 23                                                                              
The 12 hour format is 11
```